# Fit Image into grid view

Tags: android, image, user-interface, gridview, imageview

I am trying to fit the image into gridview. But I don't understand from where my gridview is getting the height of the view.

The cell of the grid view is smaller than the image. I want to display the image full in a cell. But I don't want to hard code the size of the ImageView.

My codes

gridView in xml

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview_movie_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="185dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>
```

My ImageView which I am inflating.

```
 <ImageView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

And my getView method in my adapter class

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(
            mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view_item, null);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    Picasso.with(mContext).setLoggingEnabled(false);
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(imageResource[position])
            .into(imageView);

    return imageView;
}
```

This is what I get

[image: This is what I get]

And this is what is required

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What worked for me was adding this line to my image view xml.

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Now my output is just like what I wanted.
Thanks for the help every one

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, in the getView override method to add the parameters:

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER); // Replace default CENTER_CROP
// Try ScaleType.CENTER or ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE
imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8); // why not be explicit about the padding while we're at it
```

Good ol' docs will help too:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: No this piece of code doesn't help. What this does is it rescales the image to fit into those cells. What I want is actually the image should fill the cell.

Comment: Maybe try `ScaleType.FIT_CENTER` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try fitXy on ImageView it will try to fit to the edges without decreasing the pixel

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Comment: No this piece of code doesn't help. What this does is it rescales the image to fill the cell. But the cell size is same as what I I was getting for the out put previously.

Comment: I see, sorry about the mistaken answer. I think you can use adapter to populate all the image into your GridView. So you will end up with 2 xml one xml is your grid view and the other one for your view on the grid. so you just need to create an adapter  for your grid view. I will post 1 more answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is your Gridview add to gridview.xml

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/clueGrid"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/gameInstructions"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    />
```

add this to another xml --> grid_view_image.xml

```
<com.XXXX.view.SquareRelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:background="@drawable/grid_item_background"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/clue_found"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/itemView"/>

</com.XXXX.view.SquareRelativeLayout>
```

and that xml use SquareRelativeLayout add this Java

```
public class SquareRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Then Now you need to create your Adapter

public class ItemGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
List<Item> itemList;

public ItemGridAdapter(List<Item> itemList){
    this.itemList = itemList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return itemList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view_image, parent, false);
    }
    final ImageView itemView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemView);
    itemView.setImageDrawable("YOUR DRAWABLE");
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Then on your main class that use gridview.xml

```
ItemGridAdapter itemGridAdapter = new ItemGridAdapter(itemList);
itemGrid.setAdapter(itemGridAdapter);
```

Then you can play around on just your ImageView and layout. HopeFully this is helps!!

I saw you use Picasso here is my answer for the adapter set the image :

```
   Target target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                itemView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                // Meh
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                // Meh
            }
        };

    Picasso.with(convertView.getContext())
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(target);
```